# How do I create a variable named for the folder that is my current working directory?

Tags: python-2.7, variables, spyder, pwd

I want to create a variable that's value is the name of the folder that I am working in. I can use pwd to see the working directory but I cannot figure out if there is a way to save the pwd output as a variable or better yet make a variable with only the current folder not the entire directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2.7

import os

current_folder = os.getcwd().split(os.sep)[-1]

print(current_folder)
```

Comment: That's perfect! Thank you!